# Emoji in R [UTF-8 encoding]

Tags: r, twitter, encoding, utf-8, emoji

I'm trying to make an emoji analysis on R.
I have stored some tweets where there are emojis.

Here is one of the tweet that I want to analyze :

```
> tweetn2
[1] "Programme du week-end: \xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\x83\xed\xa0\xbc \xed\xbe\xb6\xed\xa0\xbc 
    \xed\xbd\xbb\xed\xa0\xbc\xed\xbd\xbb\xed\xa0\xbc \xed\xbd\xbb\xed\xa0\xbc\xed\xbd\xbb"
```

To be sure that I have "UTF-8":

```
> Encoding(tweetn2)
[1] "UTF-8
```

" 
Now when I'm trying to recognize some characters, it's not working fine

```
> grepl("\\xed",tweetn2)
[1] FALSE
```

or

```
> grepl("xed",tweetn2)
[1] FALSE
```

But it seems that emojis "\xed\xa0\xbd" are not "UTF-8" encoding because I get an error message when I write :

```
> str(tweetn2)
Error in str.default(tweetn2) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

I find a kind of solution by using iconv( ) function and "ASCII" encoding there :
http://www.r-bloggers.com/emoticons-decoder-for-social-media-sentiment-analysis-in-r/

But I want to keep using "UTF-8" for my analysis because it works well with french special letters (à, é, è, ê, ë, û, etc.. )

So do you have an idea how I can get above it?

Thanks

Comment: only use a single backslash: `grepl("\xed",tweetn2)`. `\xed` is a single character, so there is no backslash there to escape and your string does not contain the substring `"xed"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not working :  
  `> grepl("\xed", tweetn2)  
[1] FALSE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string is invalid UTF-8, as indicated. What you have there is UTF-16 encoded with UTF-8. So `\xED\xA0\xBD` is the high surrogate [U+D83D](https://codepoints.net/U+D83D), -- and `\xED\xB2\x83` is the low surrogate [U+DC83](https://codepoints.net/U+DC83)

If you apply the magical [High,Low -> Codepoint formula](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-formulae), you'll end up with the actual codepoint:

```
(0xD83D - 0xD800) * 0x400 + 0xDC83 - 0xDC00 + 0x10000 = 0x1F483
```

You'll see this is the [dancer emoji](https://codepoints.net/U+1F483). Unfortunately I don't have a suggestion for you, as I'm not that familiar with R. But I can say you'd certainly want to get yourself in a position where this data is double encoded! Hope that helps bump you along the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)
It helps me a lot

Comment: How does one go from High surrogate as \xED\xA0\xBD to U+D83D? I cannot se the way to go from U+D83D to \xED\xA0\xBD either.

Answer (score 0):

I use `iconv(tweet, 'UTF-8', 'latin1', 'byte')` to preserve characters with tilde:

```
> tweetn2
[1] "Prógrämmè dü week-eñd: \xed��\xed�\u0083\xed��\xed��\xed��\xed��\xed��\xed��\xed��\xed�� "
> iconv(tweetn2, 'UTF-8', 'latin1', 'byte')
[1] "Prógrämmè dü week-eñd: <ed><a0><bd><ed><b2><83><ed><a0><bc><ed><bd><bb><ed><a0><bc><ed><bd><bb><ed><a0><bc><ed><bd><bb><ed><a0><bc><ed><bd><bb> "
```

As for the emoji decoding I would suggest using a function implementing nj_'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35704697/7078119). Or directly using an emoji dictionary like the one I [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42012905/7078119).

```
unicode2hilo <- function(unicode){
   hi = floor((unicode - 0x10000)/0x400) + 0xd800
   lo = (unicode - 0x10000) + 0xdc00 - (hi-0xd800)*0x400
   hilo = paste('0x', as.hexmode(c(hi,lo)), sep = '')
   return(hilo)
}

hilo2unicode <- function(hi,lo){
   unicode = (hi - 0xD800) * 0x400 + lo - 0xDC00 + 0x10000 
   unicode = paste('0x', as.hexmode(unicode), sep = '')
   return(unicode)
}
```