# Twitter emoji encoding problems with twitteR and R

Tags: r, twitter, encoding, utf-8, emoji

I'm trying to build a way to find emojis in twitter and relate them to the unicode table that one can find in unicode.org but I'm finding hard to identify them because of what I think are encoding problems or simply my misunderstanding on this topic. In short, what I did is build a "library" of emojis from the table found in http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html that contains the title and the code point (code) of the emoji. I scrapped this in R with the library *rvest*.

The problem comes when I grab the information from twitter with the twitteR API in R. As the codes for the emojis do not look at all like the ones in this table.

Let's have an example with the emoji of the 100 (one hundred points) red icon. This is the number 1468 in the before linked table and its code point code is:

```
U+1F4AF
```

Now, when I grab it from twitter, first of all it is shown like this in the status class that the API has builtin to work with the tweets.

```
\xed��\xed��
```

Then, once I convert it to a dataframe, I do it also with a builtin function from the twitter API. For example:

```
tweet$toDataFrame()
```

The emoji becomes this:

```
<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B2><U+00AF>
```

I tried to convert it with the function *iconv* in R, with the following code:

```
iconv(tweet$text, from="UTF-8", to="ASCII", "byte)
```

and I only manage to make it look like this:

```
<ed><a0><bd><ed><b2><af>
```

So, wrapping up and at the end of my tests, I got to the following results:

```
<ed><a0><bd><ed><b2><af>
<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B2><U+00AF>
\xed��\xed��
```

None of which look like the code point specified by the table:

```
U+1F4AF
```

Is there any possibility to transform between the two strings?
What am I missing? Why is twitter returning this information for emojis?

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't know anything about enconding before, but after days of reading I think I know what is going on. I don't understand perfectly how the encoding for emoji works, but I stumbled upon the same problem and solved it.

You want to map `\xed��\xed��` to its name-decoded version: *hundred points*. A sensible way could be to scrape a dictionary online and use a key, such as Unicode, to replace it. In this case it would be `U+1F4AF`.
The conversions you show are not different encodings but different notation for the same encoded emoji:

1. `as.data.frame(tweet)` returns `<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B2><U+00AF>`.
2. `iconv(tweet, from="UTF-8", to="ASCII", "byte")` returns `<ed><a0><bd><ed><b2><af>`.

So using Unicode directly isn't feasible. Another way could be to use a dictionary that already encodes emoji in the `<ed>...<ed>...` way like the one here: [emoji list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/today-is-a-good-day/Emoticons/master/emDict.csv). Voilà! Only her list is incomplete because it comes from 
a dictionary that contains fewer emoticons.

**The fast solution is** to simply scrape a more complete dictionary and map the `<ed>...<ed>...` with its corresponding english text translation. I have done that already and **posted** [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felipesua/sampleTexts/master/emojis.csv).

Although the fact that nobody else posted a list with the proper encoding bugged me. In fact, most dictionaries I found had an UTF-8 encoding using not an `<ed>...<ed>...` representation but rather `<f0>...`. It turns out they are both correct UTF-8 encodings for the same unicode `U+1F4AF` only the Bytes are read differently.

**Long answer**. The tweet is read in UTF-16 and then converted to UTF-8, and here is where conversions diverge. When the read is done by pairs of bytes the result will be UTF-8 `<ed>...<ed>...`, when it is read by chunks of four bytes the result will be UTF-8 `<f0>...` (Why is this? I don't fully understand, but I suspect it has something to do with the architecture of your processor).

So a slower (but more conscious) way to solve your problem is to scrape the `<f0>...` dictionary, convert it to UTF-16, convert it back to UTF-8 by pairs and you'll end up with two `<ed>...`. These two `<ed>...` is known as the low-high surrogate pair representation for the Unicode `U+xxxxx`.

As an example:

```
unicode <- 0x1F4Af

# Multibyte Version
intToUtf8(unicode)

# Byte-pair Version
hilo <- unicode2hilo(unicode)
intToUtf8(hilo)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "\xf0\u009f\u0092�"
[1] "\xed��\xed��"
```

Which, again, using `iconv(..., 'utf-8', 'latin1', 'byte')`, is the same as:

```
[1] "<f0><9f><92><af>"
[1] "<ed><a0><bd><ed><b2><af>"
```

**PS1.**:
Function `unicode2hilo` is a simple linear transformation of hi-lo to unicode

```
unicode2hilo <- function(unicode){
   hi = floor((unicode - 0x10000)/0x400) + 0xd800
   lo = (unicode - 0x10000) + 0xdc00 - (hi-0xd800)*0x400
   hilo = paste('0x', as.hexmode(c(hi,lo)), sep = '')
   return(hilo)
}

hilo2unicode <- function(hi,lo){
   unicode = (hi - 0xD800) * 0x400 + lo - 0xDC00 + 0x10000 
   unicode = paste('0x', as.hexmode(unicode), sep = '')
   return(unicode)
}
```

**PS2.**:
I would recommend using `iconv(tweet, 'UTF-8', 'latin1', 'byte')` to preserve special characters like áäà.

**PS3.**:
To replace the emoji with its english text, tag, hash, or anything you want to map it to, I would suggest using DFS in a graph of emojis because there are some emojis whose unicode is the concatenation of other simpler unicodes (i.e. `<f0><9f><a4><b8><e2><80><8d><e2><99><82><ef><b8><8f>` is a *man cartwheeling*, while independently `<f0><9f><a4><b8>` is *person cartwheeling*, `<e2><80><8d>` is nothing, `<e2><99><82>` is a *male sign*, and  `<ef><b8><8f>` is nothing) and while *man cartwheeling* and *person cartwheeling male sign* are obviously semantically related, I prefer the more faithfull translation.

Comment: Funny that I've been fighting with this and solved it two days ago. Still, your solution and explanation is a lot better than what I could come up with. This is the kind of answer that deserves the biggest "accept as answer" ever.

Hope that this is useful for lots of other people.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by Felipe Suárez Colmenares is excellent because it describes the mechanics of this issue, but I wanted to point you [here](https://lyons7.github.io/portfolio/2017-10-04-emoji-dictionary/), which is a dictionary I made with the < ed > R encoding specifically for Twitter. I also have code on how to go through and identify prose versions of emojis. Thought this might be easier for people who stumble into this problem in the future. The dictionary is up to date to the most recent Unicode version (9) and once the even newer one comes out I'll update it then too.

Answer (score 1):

Please try type this: iconv(tweet$text, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")

There you have also similar discussion:
[Emoticons in Twitter Sentiment Analysis in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748190/emoticons-in-twitter-sentiment-analysis-in-r)

Regards,
Magda