# How to transform the emoji code to the unicode?

Tags: python, r, twitter, unicode, emoji

I am currently doing a sentiment analysis project about the online tweets. The tweets were collected by a previous guy in my group using R. And now I am using Python. A sample  of the collected tweets is given below:

```
Wherever we go with it becomes a cafe!
.....
<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B3><U+00B7>: mad.maps  -  "Slow down and <url>
```

It seems like the `<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B3><U+00B7>` corresponds to the emoji  after checking the original tweet. Hence, I really want to know how to transform the `<ed>...<ed>...` things to the correct emoji. Or how could I link the  `<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B3><U+00B7>` stuff to  's Unicode, which is `U+1F4F7`?

Any help and insights would be appreciated! Thank you!

PS:

1. The Emoji-Unicode pair I am using is given here: [Full Emoji List,
   v11.0](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f4f7)
2. This pdf file also provides some emoji-emoji_code pair, but it is
   not enough: [emoji to emoji code](https://jums.academy/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/A_Baum.pdf)

Comment: Do you hapen to know how he got the `<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B3><U+00B7>`. Maybe he knows what encoding or notation it is?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999896/twitter-emoji-encoding-problems-with-twitter-and-r) you go :-)